# Slow wired connection on Linux but normal speed on Windows

Tags: networking, performance, internet, troubleshooting

I installed Ubuntu, Pop_OS, Manjaro, Neon, and Deepin, to my desktop PC (specs at bottom). My internet speed was very slow, basically unusable.

Windows gives a normal 15 Mb down and 10 Mb up, but when I'm in Linux the download drops to *40 b* down.

I've tried disabling IPv6 and setting the DNS to 8.8.8.8 with no success. I'm guessing that it is something related to my hardware maybe? Because I have Manjaro installed on my laptop and the speeds are normal.

I had Arch installed on my PC some time ago (2/3 months) and back then I didn't have these issues.

PC specs:

- [MSI h61m-e22/w8](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/H61M-E22W8/Specification)
- i7-3770
- 16 GB RAM
- RTX 2060

Comment: Try to take tcpdump or/and run download command with `strace`, also check if any firewall enabled or any issue with network interface.

Comment: According to your link you have an RTL 8111E ethernet adapter. Just a guess, but maybe you're using the wrong driver `r8169` instead of `r8168` as described [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/no-wired-network-realtek-rtl8111-8168-8411/22501/2)? Which module is listed if you run `lsmod | grep r816`?

Comment: @Freddy and here's a great example of why just providing a link in a comment isn't reliable. This link is being redirected to a totally unrelated topic.